# Python calling methods that return booleans, like `issuperset`, memory friendly?

Tags: python, c, set, cpython

I wrote some code assuming that a check for a superset would be memory friendly and lead to less fragmentation since it returns a boolean (a_list *is* always no bigger than 2 elements of very small strings, on the same order as `foo` and `bar`). e.g.

```
OK_SET = set('foo', 'bar')

def are_args_ok(a_list):
    if not OK_SET.issuperset(a_list): # expected to run a lot
        raise ValueError('bad value in a_list') # virtually never
```

And I considered the above preferable to the below, if only for readability, but also because [I assumed it's better not to create lots of unnecessary lists](http://hbfs.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/python-memory-management-part-ii/), and I would hope it doesn't create any other objects since it only returns a boolean.

```
def are_args_ok(a_list):
    if [i for i in a_list if i not in ['foo', 'bar']]: # expected to run a lot
        raise ValueError('bad value in a_list') # virtually never
```

However, I'm not clear on all of the inner workings of Python. Therefore, I've been reading the [CPython source (excerpt below)](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/88814d1f8c32/Objects/setobject.c#l1796) and it appears the check for a superset creates a set object of the other if it's not already a set:

```
static PyObject *
set_issuperset(PySetObject *so, PyObject *other)
{
    PyObject *tmp, *result;

    if (!PyAnySet_Check(other)) {
        tmp = make_new_set(&PySet_Type, other);
        if (tmp == NULL)
            return NULL;
        result = set_issuperset(so, tmp);
        Py_DECREF(tmp);
        return result;
    }
    return set_issubset((PySetObject *)other, (PyObject *)so);
}
```

So it looks like I create a new set when given a list as my other, so my assumption was wrong, even if it is more readable. I think the second code may actually be faster, at least it is when I test with Python 2.6. So my question is, is the first code preferable to the second in terms of memory performance and fragmentation?

Is there a strictly dominating approach that I have not yet considered?

This answers relevant questions about performance:

```
must= '''MUST=set(['a','b'])

def validate(vals):
    if not MUST.issuperset(vals):
        raise Exception'''

mustdiff= '''MUST=set(['a','b'])

def validate(vals):
    if set(vals) - MUST:
        raise Exception'''

must2= '''def validate(vals):
    if not set(['a','b']).issuperset(vals):
        raise Exception'''

old_list = '''def validate(vals):
    if [i for i in vals if i not in ['a','b']]:
        raise Exception
'''

old_tup = '''def validate(vals):
    if [i for i in vals if i not in ('a','b')]:
        raise Exception
'''
test = "validate(['a']); validate(['a', 'b'])"

def main():
    print timeit.repeat(test, setup=must)
    print timeit.repeat(test, setup=mustdiff)
    print timeit.repeat(test, setup=must2)
    print timeit.repeat(test, setup=old_list)
    print timeit.repeat(test, setup=old_tup)
```

outputs:

```
[0.90473995592992651, 0.90407950738062937, 0.90170756738780256]
[1.0068785656071668, 1.0049370642036592, 1.0076947689335611]
[1.4705243140447237, 1.4697376920521492, 1.4727534788248704]
[0.74187539617878429, 0.74010685502116758, 0.74236680853618964]
[0.74886594826284636, 0.74639892541290465, 0.74475293549448907]
```

Comment: The temporary set will die before `issuperset` returns. If `a_list` is always small, it might very well always allocate the same single slot for the set. Doesn't mean it'll be faster, but it sure is more convenient.

Comment: a_list *is* always small. Typically 2 elements at the most.

Comment: Oh and btw if you can write `['foo', 'bar']` for `OK_SET` you should try out `('foo', 'bar')` which would avoid creating a list on every single `in` test (it creates the tuple once, at compile time, and loads it when needed).

Comment: Can you link to the source on that? I haven't dug into function compilation yet.

Comment: The implementation is probably spread over many separate files (this optimization touches on bytecode compilation, the `pyc` format, and the interpreter loop), but you can observe it using `dis` (look out for the `LOAD_CONST` opcode).

Comment: Note that over the course of 1,000,000 loops, there is at most a difference of about 700ms. Is this significant for your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a small number of items, this seems to be slightly faster than several other things I tried:

```
    .
    .
    .
kiss = '''MUST=['a','b']

def validate(vals):
    for i in vals:
        if i not in MUST:
            raise Exception
'''

test = "validate(['a']); validate(['a', 'b'])"

def main():
    print '    must:', min(timeit.repeat(test, setup=must))
    print 'mustdiff:', min(timeit.repeat(test, setup=mustdiff))
    print '   must2:', min(timeit.repeat(test, setup=must2))
    print 'old_list:', min(timeit.repeat(test, setup=old_list))
    print ' old_tup:', min(timeit.repeat(test, setup=old_tup))
    print '    kiss:', min(timeit.repeat(test, setup=kiss))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Accepting because this is strictly dominates (superior on every dimension) other solutions. Although, slightly faster with MUST as a set instead of a list.

Comment: I didn't try it with `MUST` as a `set` because doing so seemed to slow down other things I tried. BTW, strictly speaking `validate()` does not return a boolean -- it either returns `None` or raises an exception and so never returns.

Answer (score 3):

> I think the second code may actually be faster, at least it is when I
>   test with Python 2.6.

I would be shocked if that were the case -- what are the sizes of the lists in question? My guess is that, maybe, the conversion of the list into a set has some constant overhead that negates any performance benefit from using the set operations.

The set operations [give you asymptotically optimal performance](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for this kind of operation. I would expect the `issuperset` method to give you the best performance, followed perhaps by:

```
if not set(a_list) - OK_SET:...
```

with `O(len(a_list))` performance. Note that using the global variable `OK_SET` is also going to significantly hurt your performance.

That being said: unless you are testing sets which contain thousands of elements, the difference is probably negligible. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. If your production code is actually only testing two elements, I doubt you will find much difference.

Comment: the list is very small, see edit near intro paragraph. I'm using Python 2.6, and the global variable strictly dominates in performance compared to creating it on every call. +1 for the help though.

Comment: If the conversion to a `set` is the culprit, `if not set(a_list) - OK_SET` won't improve on that (it will actually create *two* sets, one like the one built in `issuperset` and another as result of `-`).

Comment: @AaronHall have you tested that? I don't believe that using a local variable will result in it being re-created every call. Failing that, use it as the default value of a parameter to the function -- that certainly is evaluated exactly once. But there is a [large overhead on global variables](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Local_Variables)

Comment: @delnan Yes, I'm not suggesting that that version avoids the overhead -- I said that it will be worse than `issuperset`, but provided it with the reference to the Python wiki because its performance is well-documented, and asymptotically optimal. In the case of a two-element list though, I really doubt that any micro-optimization will make a significant difference.